# Is it legal to download Darktable in European countries?

Tags: lightroom, legal, darktable

The functionality of Darktable is very good so I thought I would switch from Lightroom to Darktable. Can I download it in Germany or any other European countries which have strict legal standards for downloading software?

Comment: Why would it be illegal to download any regular software?.... It's not like Darktable is hacking software or anything with malicious intent

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question about any piece of software and not specific to photography in any way.

Comment: @PhilipKendall why it’s totally related to photography editing

Comment: @Ryka This would rather be a question for law.se. because it's about downloading and not about editing

Comment: @PhilipKendall but there is no lawyer who studies on software issues and I thought it would be better to ask the users who regularly use it knows about it than any lawyer.

Comment: "there is no lawyer who studies on software issues" There are many. To take the possibly the most obvious example, [Software Freedom Law Center](https://www.softwarefreedom.org/).

Comment: @PhilipKendall thank you till I didn’t know there was blog like this and this is the reason I posted the question. Ultimately to know the unknown things

Comment: @Ryka `To know the unknown things` is exactly the reason it is desirable to do some research before posting a question here. I am glad you found our community and hope it will be helpful for you when you *use* Darktable. Please visit the [tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help) section to learn more about using this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Darktable is free software and it is perfectly legal to download it in entire EU. About download in Germany - download the software from [official web site](https://www.darktable.org/install/) or from official mirror site.

About Lightroom - it is legal again if you download it from Adobe web site. And its legal to use it on the time of trial period.

Do not use p2p/torrent to download LR software!

Comment: Why shouldn't I download Debian, which includes Darktable, via BitTorrent? (Yes, I know I'm being slightly pedantic here)

Comment: Because AFAIK in Germany network traffic is monitored and maybe you will get in your mail a fine. Of course you can complain and provide evidences Debian is free software, etc. But why put yourself in troubles?

Comment: @PhilipKendall, I have no details how they monitor it, but fines can be something like 500 euro for downloaded movie.

Comment: Errrr....and why would they do that? There is nothing, I repeat, **nothing** in European or German law that prohibits you from using BitTorrent. It is, however, illegal to download pirated software - no matter whether you use P2P or not. If your P2P software uploads pirated software (which you downloaded before) while you download darktable with it, you may get fined - for uploading, not for downloading.

Comment: @flolilo, I explain the current situation...

Comment: How many of downvoters work or live in Germany?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I do. You can't be fined for just "using bittorrent".

Comment: @ChrisH, so do I. And have pretty good info about those things.Of course there are some details, which are more appropriate for Superuser SE

Comment: @RomeoNinov if you think anybody in Germany gets fines for using torrent software without specific evidence that they were using it to up- or download things in violation of the relevant copyright/licensing, then your info isn't nearly as good as you think it is. There is no legal risk involved in using torrent or other p2p software to acquire software released under GPL.

Comment: @ChrisH, errors happen. And then you should prove this is free software. It's wise to stay away from torrents/p2p.

Comment: @RomeoNinov that's like saying you should never travel abroad because you might be wrongly accused of espionage.

Comment: This is blatantly false information Romeo. Yes, you can get fined for using P2P. This will ALWAYS be because of the contents of what you are downloading, and thus you may as well have downloaded the regular way. Such examples include illicitly acquired media, say movies. Fines *will* list exactly what has been downloaded. Using P2P is completely legal and is used in other, legal, instances instead of just downloading pirated files. You will never "accidentally" receive a fine for downloading.

Comment: "errors happen" - indeed. That's why we have courts and lawyers. Errors can happen to anyone at any time: You could, for example, get fined for driving too fast although you neither own a car nor have a driver's license and although never having bewn at the place of the speed trap in your while life. Does it happen often? Well, I heard of more of these cases (3) than about P2P-cases (0). Add that to the clear lack of laws that prohibit P2P usage and...

Comment: @flolilo, I have several examples (of fines) about usage of P2P and one of them was wrong. But as you know this kind of statistic should be checked on government level.

Comment: As stated: That's why we have lawyers and courts. I find it very hard to believe that the sentence was "use of illicit P2P software". I could be wrong of course, but I guess that at least heise/c't and/or other computer-specific news outlets would publish such cases, especially if there was an error involved.

Comment: Romeo again. I refuse to believe those fines were for using P2P as that's not illegal AT ALL. Those fines must have been about the the data acquired with that sevice. You have not mentioned anything to prove your argument, at all.

Answer (score 5):

"darktable is released under the terms of the GNU General Public License Version 3 or later." -https://www.darktable.org/about/

It is free software, unlike Lightroom.  As a point of clarification, it is not illegal to download Lightroom either, as long as you have paid for it.  If I'm reading between the lines of your question correctly, you are asking if downloading darktable is breaking intellectual property laws. (As downloading Lightroom without paying for it would be)  The short answer: No.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if the *official* web site of any software has download links, it is legal to download.  This includes proprietary software (eg, updates and trials) as long as you abide by the terms of the license.

There have been exceptions in the past.  So if you have any concerns, you should contact the developers directly.

Comment: It would still be legal to download it from any other side. What could be illegal is to host it without permission of the authors, but never downloading it in good faith (because how would you know?). That is...as long as it is not clear that the software you downloaded was pirated (i.e. manipulated to allow the circumvention of licensing). But of course, if you really are paranoid about this, contacting the developers is the best idea.

Comment: There is software that uses GPL components, but don't abide by the terms (by releasing source code).  Such software is illegal, despite developers making the binaries available.  There are other scenarios, but they usually don't affect end users directly.  As far as I know, none applies to DarkTable.